# Schedule Job JobType I and K

Tags: scheduled-job

When navigating to Scheduled Jobs in our org, we have a number of scheduled jobs with types "Scheduled Apex" or "Data Export". But I'm also seeing a couple jobs with types "I" and "K". I'm trying to track down what one of these is doing, but I'm also trying to figure out what these jobtypes mean since I don't see them as options within the [CronJobDetail JobType possibilities](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_cronjobdetail.htm). Any idea on what that means or where I might be able to find more details on the scheduled job? I only have the option to "Delete" and not to "Manage". Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**K** is for `Metalytics` or the `Ask Data for Salesforce` job which is explained in this [help article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000359016&type=1) as being a system-generated scheduled job in orgs where Tableau CRM is enabled.

> It loads updated data used to power recommendations in your Tableau
> CRM home page. It runs in the background once a day to ensure that the
> recommendations you get from Ask Data for Salesforce are up to date.

This is something new with Winter '22 ([Choose Your Search Experience Beta](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_bi_onboard_search.htm&type=5&release=234)).

`Setup --> Analytics --> Settings --> Enable Ask Data for Salesforce`

---

**I** is the [Optimizer App](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.optimizer_kick_off.htm&type=5) if you set it up to automatically run monthly.

`Setup --> Optimizer --> Decide if the app should automatically run and update`

[image]

---

You should be able to get a clue about what it does by the `JobName` as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Incredibly helpful answer - thanks a ton!